# Incorporating a knowledge base / blog for Q & A on an engineering website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have an engineering firm and our website was built using Visual Studio 2010 / asp.net 4.0 / VB.  Recently, a client (GM) requested that we have a **knowledge base** where they can input their questions, and we can answer 'em.  Kind of like a FAQ, or a Lessons Learned type of thing.  But it'll require that they'll be able to log in and ask their own questions.

For instance:  *Q:  How would I incorporate multiple machine vision systems into a bead detection application?
               A: You would need to use a software such as PPT and have multiple fixtures in order to assimilate the cameras accordingly.*

I'm terrible at databases; I can basically run an SQL query, and that's about it!  lol.  And I'm not a programmer by trade.  Can I do this without a database?  Can anyone guide me in the right direction here?  I mean, is there something out there that's open-source, or at least something that's easy to implement?

Any guidance in this regard would be greatly greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: You can hit the wiki, or check [this list](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/) for other CRM solutions that you can incorporate.  I think they're all OSS.  Web platform installer is your friend.

Comment: Will, thank you for the information, and I'm not trying to disrupt the site.  I just thought it was an appropriate question.  Could you please tell me what I did wrong?  Or where I should have posted the question?  Thanks!

Comment: NP.  Remember, [meta] is always available for learning and asking about SO.  Your question is very open ended, and is considered a "shopping question" (whether its free or not), both of which are discouraged here.

Comment: Okay ... thanks again for the information, and I won't make the same mistake again.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install a [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki).

There are [plenty of different ones](http://www.wikimatrix.org/) out there - some written in .NET lanaguages.

Comment: Oded, I have looked at the comparison of Wikis, and I cannot seem to find one in VB.  I found ASP.NET, but it's written in C#.  Do you have any additional suggestions?  Thanks again for taking the time to respond -- much appreciated!

Comment: @JasonWeber - You seem to have a deep misunderstanding about .NET - all .NET languages compile to a single language, IL. So long as the assemblies are CLS compliant, you can use them in any .NET language.

Comment: Thank you once again Oded -- I appreciate your knowledge. And yes, my understanding of .net is rudimentary, at best, but nice people like you are helping me learn and understand.  Again, I appreciate you taking the time to help!